# Fermat's Little Theorem problem: $ 445^{445} + 225^{225} \pmod{9}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

Here is the problem:

$ 445^{445} + 225^{225}  \pmod{9}$

I found out that for $ 445^{445}  \pmod{9} = 7$.

but for $ 225^{225}  \pmod{9}$ when I do this:

$ (225 \bmod 9)^{225  \bmod 8}$ for the first equation I have $0$ mod.

What should I do?

Comment: (445**445)%9 = 4, checked with Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $4+4+5\equiv4\pmod9\implies445\equiv4\pmod9$

$$\implies445^{445}\equiv4^{445}$$

As $9$ is not prime, we need to use Euler's Totient Function.

$$\phi(9)=6,445\equiv1\pmod6\implies4^{445}\equiv4^1\pmod9$$

and

$$225\equiv0\pmod9\implies225^n\equiv0$$

Comment: can you please explain me the first line of the solution. I understood everything else, thanks so much!

Comment: @boka18, See https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Divisibility_rules/Rule_for_3_and_9_proof

Comment: @boka18 This classical technique is known as [casting out nines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casting_out_nines). It works as follows ${\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ \color{#c00}{10 \equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, a+b\color{#c00}{10}+\color{#c00}{10}^2 c+\cdots\equiv a+b+c+\cdots.\,$ Therefore an integer is congruent to its *digit sum* modulo $9$. The same holds mod $3$ since also $10\equiv 1\pmod 3,\,$ In your problem it is simpler to work mod $3\ $ (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Since $225 \equiv 0 \mod 9$, one has $225^n \equiv 0^n \equiv 0 \mod 9$ for $n \ge 1$, so every positive power of $225$ is also $0$ modulo $9$.

To see this more intuitively for this particular case: $225 \equiv 0 \mod 9$ just means $9$ divides $225$. Then of course $9$ also divides $225^n$.

On the other hand to reduce the exponent modulo $8$ is not correct. 
The modulus $9$ is not prime. So this is not a situation where you can apply Fermat's little theorem. Instead, reduce modulo $\varphi(9)= 6$.

In light of this you should double-check your first result. As pointed out by others it is in fact not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ \color{#c00}{4^{\large 3}} = 64\equiv  \color{#c00}{\bf 1},\ $ so $\,\ 4^{\large 1+3n}\equiv 4(\color{#c00}{4^{\large 3}})^{\large n}\equiv 4(\color{#c00}{\bf 1})^{\large n}\equiv 4$

**Notes** $\ 445 = \color{#0a0}{\bf 1}+3n\,$ since $\,{\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ 445\equiv 4+4+5\equiv\color{#0a0}{\bf 1}\,$ by $\,10\equiv 1\,$ (casting $3$'s)

Our calculation used standard [Congruence Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) - here the Product and Power Rules.

You cannot apply little Fermat since the modulus $\,9\,$ is not prime. Instead you could use a generalization [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) using $\,\phi(9) = 6\,$ to reduce the exponent mod $\,6.\,$